# Configuring a backup DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I would like to setup a backup DNS server. 
I have added all my name servers in my domain name panel. (ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com, etc ...)

If a person would try to go to domain.com and the first name server would fail, will it automatically try and use ns2.domain.com?

All my DNS servers have the same master zones configured. Is that the way to go? Is it that easy or am I missing something here? :)

Comment: Please do both yourself and anyone using your system a favour and get a decent understanding of how DNS works. It's so absolutely vital and central to the operation of the Internet that anyone hosting anything should understand it, at least at the basic level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a person would try to go to domain.com and the first name server would fail, will it automatically try and use ns2.domain.com?

Assuming you've correctly configured everything - after a short timeout period, the second server will be queried.

> All my dns servers have the same master zones configured. Is that the way to go?

It's probably easiest to configure one as a master and another as a slave, so that you only have to update records once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have however started to use a 3rd party dns service. I'm not managing my own dns server anymore.